# Attaching an object tree to object context in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have an EDM with the following three types: Foo, Bar and Foob. Foob is a subclass of Foo. Foo has a collection of Bar entities. Bar has a collection of Foo entities. I want to add a new Foo object to the collection, along with it's Bar and associated Foob objects. Such that the following code would work:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(){Name = "Foo"};
using(var ctx = new EntityContext())
{
ctx.Foo.Attach(foo);
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.Items.Add(new Foob(){Name="Foob1"};
bar.Items.Add(new Foob(){Name="Foob2"};
foo.Bars.Add(bar);
ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

However the above code gives me the exception below:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.tblFoo' with unique index.

Comment: Try to attach after 'ctx.SaveChanges();', because i suggest that after your changes was saved db have created foo object id(In case if it autoincrement is set to true).

Answer (score 1):

Try to check sql code that executed for this in SQL profiler. May be you forgot set autoincrement for Foob entity.